# Display 50 rows per page from mysql in table but allow to search whole table

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have an mysql table which table which display over 10,000 data in page.

I am using an ajax search where on typing the name, it automatically display result.

I want to Limit the no. of rows displayed in page since 10,000 rows does take lot of space and also don't look very professional. 
For this I used

```
LIMIT  10
```

and It displays only 10 rows in page but problem is then I'm restricted to search within this 10 rows. If I type any other name in search box which don't below to any rows of this Ten, Then it don't find anything.

So is there anyway to hide the rest of rows and only show 100 per page and also allow to search for whole table.

Here is my code to display result.

```html
<input type="text" style="height:35px; color:#222;" name="filter" value="" id="filter" placeholder="Search Students..." autocomplete="off" />
<br><br>
<table class="hoverTable" id="resultTable" data-responsive="table" style="text-align: left;">
 <thead>
  <tr>
  
   <th width="20%"> Full Name </th>
   <th width="15%"> District</th>
   <th width="5%"> Gender </th>
   <th width="5%"> Year </th>
   <th width="25%"> Email</th>
   <th width="5%"> Phone</th>

  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  
   <?php
   
    include('../connect.php');
    $result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM student ORDER BY id DESC");
    $result->execute();
    for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){
    
   ?>
  

   <td>  <a  href="viewstudentuser.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"> <?php echo $row['name']; ?> <?php echo $row['last_name']; ?> </a> </td>
   <td><?php echo $row['district']; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['gender']; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['yoa']; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $row['phone']; ?></td>
  
   </tr>
   <?php
    }
   ?>
  
  
  
 </tbody>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use Datatables and serverside processing https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `LIMIT` in conjunction with `OFFSET`.

Example for `per_page = 50` and `page = 3`

```
SELECT * FROM student 
WHERE some_column LIKE '%search%'
LIMIT (3 - 1)*50, 50
ORDER BY id DESC
```

You can view some examples here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/php-mysql-limit-clause